# Error code 400 With Evernote OAuth (Signpost)

Tags: java, oauth, evernote, signpost

I am trying to connect to Evernote with OAuth and Signpost using one of the examples I saw in the dev forums, but for some reason I keep getting error code 400 (Bad Request). Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String consumerKey = "key_here";
        String consumerSecret = "secret_key_here";

        OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerKey,
                consumerSecret);
        consumer.setMessageSigner(new PlainTextMessageSigner());
        OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                "https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth",
                "https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth",
                "https://sandbox.evernote.com/OAuth.action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected HttpRequest createRequest(String endpointUrl)
                    throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                        endpointUrl).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
                return new HttpURLConnectionRequestAdapter(connection);
            }
        };
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
        System.out.println(authUrl);
    }
```

(and before anyone asks, yes I did replace the placeholders with my own keys)
And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 400 (Bad Request)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:218)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:74)
    at com.zakta.evernote.module.EvernoteAuthenticationTest.main(EvernoteAuthenticationTest.java:44)
Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Service provider responded in error: 400 (Bad Request)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:245)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:193)
    ... 2 more
```

I seem to be using the correct procedure here, but maybe something changed? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Current Evernote OAuth doesn't allow OUT_OF_BOUND. You need to pass the callback URL.